# Mongoid: show entire mongodb object with embeded_in objects in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

```
class Parent
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :children
  field :title
end

class Child
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :parent
  field :name
end
```

Rails console

```
parent = Parent.new(:title => "Hello World")
parent.children << Child.new(:name => "Pedro")
parent
#=> #<Parent _id: 4e2330286254cc0e7d000007, _type: nil, title: "Hellow World">
```

So how can I inspect entire object in Rails console, till children are embeded in my `parent` like I can do it in mogodb console

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e2330286254cc0e7d000007"),
  "title": "Hello World",
  "children" : [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e0"),
      "name" : "Pedro"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to inspect the attributes of your Mongoid object like so:

```
parent.attributes.inspect
```